# Use Final Value In Iterative Process

Tags: r, matrix, sapply, cbind

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
## Round 1
b <- c(5000,2500)
r <- c(2,2.1) 
pm <- c(200,240)

I <- b*(r/1200) 
pi <- pm-I
end <- b-pi  
end

## Round 2 
b1 <- end 
r1 <- (2.3,2.3) 
I1 <- b1*(r/1200)
pi1 <- pm-I1 
end1 <- b1-pi1 
end1
```

This produces the proper output, which is shown below in the post. But, you can see how this might get annoying for about 30 rounds so I thought that I would be able to use a *sapply function. So I attempted to do:

```
r2<- matrix(c(2,2.1,2.3,2.3),nrow=2)
I2 <- sapply(b, function (x)
  x*(r2/1200)
)

pi2 <- sapply(I, function (l)
  pm-l )


end2 <- b-pi2
end2
```

Which gives:

```
[1,] 4808.333 4804.375
[2,] 2268.333 2264.375
```

This did not produce the desired output which is:

```
[1,] 4808.333 4616.347
[2,] 2264.375 2028.338
```

How exactly would I go about doing this because the "end" variables need the updated "b" value as shown in the starred part of the code below.

```
    **b1 <- end** 
    r1 <- 2.3 
    I1 <- b1*(r/1200)
    pi1 <- pm-I1 
    end1 <- b1-pi1 
    end1
```

Thank you for your time.

**Edit**

Pierre gives an answer below, but I have another question which is how would I do this process "n" number of times. Pierre's answer works for this specific question. But, I am trying to make this work when "r" and "r1" are joint in a matrix like

```
rate <- rbind(r,r1)
```

And then use an sapply function kind of like:

```
t(sapply(b, function(x) {b <- b - (pm - b*(rate/1200));b}))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation where for loops shine:

```
rlist <- list(r, r1)
x <- vector("list", 2)
for(i in 1:2) {b <- b - (pm - b*(rlist[[i]]/1200)); x[[i]] <- b}
`names<-`(as.data.frame(x), c('x', 'y'))
#         x        y
#1 4808.333 4617.549
#2 2264.375 2028.715
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I was always told to stay clear from for-loops in R.

Comment: Is the rlist function part of a special package?

Comment: My apologies. See the edit. I created a list of the "r" values

Comment: There is no difference between `sapply` and a `for` loop.

Comment: @DavidArenburg that was what I have always thought as well

Comment: @AdamWarner if you always thought so too what issue you have with Pierres `for` loop then?

Comment: I've tried a few versions of `sapply(rlist, function(x) {b <- b - (pm - b*(x/1200));b})` and couldn't get the desired output, so I'll stick with the loop.

Comment: @PierreLafortune my next question would be what if r and r1 where joint using cbind in a matrix. How would the for loop need to be modified?

Comment: replace rlist with `rtest[i,] `